# What UML diff tools exist?

Tags: uml, diff, argouml

I need to get diffs of ArgoUML diagrams. Are there any tools that provide Diffing capabilities to do UML?

I constantly make updates to my UML in SVN but I do not have a way to compare different versions.

I have seen [UML-like Diff Tool](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/02/uml-like-diff-tool/) from IntelliJ exists. But are there any other tools that don't require me to use IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EMF in Eclipse you can compare two UML diagrams.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Compare/UML_Compare

So, you need to convert your ArgoUML to EMF standard by using the following framework.

http://argo2ecore.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of these [version control tools for models](http://modeling-languages.com/version-control-tools-modeling-artifacts/) can help. They are not UML-specific but as the EMF-Compare tool mentioned before, they work with generic EMF models.

Answer (score 1):

The EMF compare project does not work well. What you get is not really usable.

What I do in my project is to save my model and my diagrams on SVN. I then just look at svn to see modifications. You can not really see the dif insode a graph but it is usually easy to find out what has been modified because the model is composed by Name of the model > Packages > classifiers. The root can therefore be traced and the modified element find out quickly.